# Teleport Method Keeps Doubling My Coordinates(Spigot)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to make a teleport wand that would teleport you one block forward, explode, and give you regeneration for 1 second but everytime I teleport it would double my coords for some reason. For example, I would go from the coordinates 383, 43, 256 to the coordinates 767, 86, 512. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Here's my Class code:

```
package com.jason.sbitems.swords;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;

public class AOTE implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public static void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        Material mat = e.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getType();

        int x = p.getLocation().getBlockX();
        int y = p.getLocation().getBlockY();
        int z = p.getLocation().getBlockZ();
        Location a = p.getLocation().add(x + 1, y, z);

        if (e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
            if (mat == Material.STICK) {
                p.getWorld().createExplosion(p.getLocation(), 0f);
                p.teleport(a);
                p.addPotionEffect(PotionEffectType.REGENERATION.createEffect(20, 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have misunderstood how the [`add()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Location.html#add(double,double,double)) method works with locations. You are *adding* the provided doubles to the current location and so you do not need to specify the coordinate again.

So to add 1 to the X coordinate, you would do so like

```java
Location a = p.getLocation().add(1, 0, 0);
```

You are doubling their coordinates by adding them again. Except for the X coordinate, where you are adding the value again plus one.

A side note, if your goal is to teleport the player one block forward, adding to the X will not always result in 'forward', depending on where the player is looking. You could achieve that with something similar to:

```java
Vector teleportTo = player.getLocation().getDirection().normalize().multiply(1);
player.teleport(player.getLocation().add(teleportTo));
```

This will allow them to be teleported into a block so you will of course need to perform your own checks and modifications.

Comment: Thank you but is there any documentation or something that I can follow to see what every method does in detail and what I can add to the methods?

Comment: Yes, I did link it in my answer (the `add()` is a hyperlink). But here's the main page: [Spigot javadocs](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/).